# How to delete current line on a text file in C#.net?

Tags: c#, string, line

In C#.net, the button I implemented reads the content of three textboxes (Name, a code and password), and connects them in a way that it becomes one single string. Then, it reads line by line on a text file in order to check if the string exists on it. If it does, it deletes the whole line in which it is present. I managed to find the string on the text file, but don't know how to delete the whole line, as the line also contains other characters and numbers.

This is the code so far inside the button:

```
string alldata = txtnomedous.Text + txtcpfdous.Text + txtsenhadous.Text;
                String fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"rato.txt");
                // compare TextBox content with file content
                if (fileContent.Contains(alldata))
                {

                    using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"rato.txt"))
                    {
                        string line = null;
                        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (line.Contains(alldata))
                            {
                                //Delete current line
                                MessageBox.Show("User " + txtnomedous.Text + " was successfuly deleted.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

And this is the text file:

```
2Rambo425.433-628-43ererssd3
1a111.111.111-11a
1Paulo111.111.111-11password2
1Momba111.111.111-11asdsad4432
2Mauricio111.111.111-22wwcssfd2
3Saulo111.111.111-11qwe1231231
```

So, for example, if "Paulo" is written in the name textbox, 111.111.111-11 in the code textbox, and "password" in the password textbox, the string alldata would be 'Paulo111.111.111-11password'. As the string exists in the text file (third line), it would delete the whole line.
How do I do this?

Comment: Ideally you cant delete the line but store an empty instead.  Also,  you can read and copy all lines to other file and delete the old file

Comment: How to store an empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
string alldata = ...

// Read from file
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("rato.txt");

// Write to file
File.WriteAllLines("rato.txt", lines.Where(line => !line.Contains(alldata)));
```

The `Where` method will filter out strings that do not contain the necessary information.